How to build a staircase report?
By "staircase report," I mean a cumulative report that takes a payment or amount from one month, and applies it to that present and all future months in a dataframe.
Using pictures of tables to illustrate.  Only looking for the code to build the dataframe, not row / column headers or formatting.
Input

Input code
revenue = pd.Series([10, 30, 20], 
                    index=['2024-01', '2024-02', '2024-03'])

Output


Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting (cf. print(revenue.to_frame())) or table formatting (cf. print(revenue.to_markdown()).

The key is, you wouldn't do this in pandas.  Pandas holds the data.  Pandas doesn't produce reports.

@TimRoberts: OP seems aware of that: "Only looking for the code to build the dataframe, not row / column headers or formatting."

I think you are wrong.  He wants to create a dataframe that prints as his report.  That's the wrong approach.

You can use np.tril to fill the lower triangle of an array (shape (3, 3) in this case). The upper triangle will get zeros above the 0th diagonal:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([10, 30, 20], index=['2024-01', '2024-02', '2024-03'])

# we need dtype `float` to allow `np.nan` assignment below
data = np.tril(s.astype(float))

data

array([[10.,  0.,  0.],
       [10., 30.,  0.],
       [10., 30., 20.]])

If you are sure that your data doesn't have zeros, you could then simply overwrite them like this:
data[data == 0] = np.nan

Output:
array([[10., nan, nan],
       [10., 30., nan],
       [10., 30., 20.]])

If you're not sure, you can use np.triu_indices and use 1 for the diagonal offset:
data[np.triu_indices(data.shape[0], 1)] = np.nan

The result you can feed to pd.DataFrame, adding the months via pd.to_datetime, Series.dt.strftime, and Series.str.upper:
months = pd.to_datetime(s.index).strftime('%b').str.upper()

out = pd.DataFrame(data, index=months, columns=months)

out

      JAN   FEB   MAR
JAN  10.0   NaN   NaN
FEB  10.0  30.0   NaN
MAR  10.0  30.0  20.0


If performance is a concern (and you need to use nptriu_indices anyway), you could also use np.tile like below. Seems marginally faster:
np.tile(s, len(s)).reshape(len(s), -1)

array([[10, 30, 20],
       [10, 30, 20],
       [10, 30, 20]], dtype=int64)

